# Задача: перевод из двоичной системы в десятеричную

Tags: c

С заранее ведомым числом работает по простому алгоритму(например 4 символа)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
   int number = 0, a1 = 0, a2 = 0, a3 = 0, a4 = 0, a10 = 0;

   printf("Please input char 4 ");
   scanf("%d", &number);

   a1 = number / 1000;
   a2 = (number - (a1 * 1000)) / 100;
   a3 = (number - ((a1 * 1000) + (a2 * 100))) / 10;
   a4 = (number - ((a1 * 1000) + (a2 * 100) + (a3 * 10)));

   a10 = a1 * 8 + a2 * 4 + a3 * 2 + a4 * 1;

   printf("%d", a10);
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

Но если чисел больше 4 или меньше я не могу понять как реализовать. Продумывал алгоритм, надо посчитать количество символов в заданном числе и с кучей условий реализовать это, но это очень "громоздко" и не могу понять как сделать короче. Учитывая что могу пользоваться только WHILE и условиями IF ELSE. Кто ни будь может подсказать алгоритм?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял задачу, но если требуется ввести с клавиатуры нолики и единички, а потом напечатать их в виде десятичного числа, то удобней вводить в цикле посимвольно и вычислять результат, который и напечатать потом.

Программа основана просто на представлении числа в определенной системе счисления (в данном случае двоичной).

Не знаю, можете ли Вы (в рамках задания) использовать сдвиги, поэтому просто умножайте на основание системы счисления.

Должно быть что-то в духе

```
int c, sum = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (!(c == '0' || c == '1')
       break;
    sum = sum * 2 + (c-'0');
}
printf ("%d\n",sum);
```

Чтобы понять, зачем из `c` вычитается `0` посмотрите таблицу символов ASCII.

Comment: А есть возможность сделать без getchar? Просто вводить символы по очереди 1 или 0 ? Или как-то по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, неплохо бы получать цифры с конца:

```
nextDigit = currNumber % 10;
currNumber = currNumber / 10;
```

и упаковывать их в массив. Вам понадобится поддерживать текущий индекс в массиве в переменной. (Если выделенного размера массива не хватает, чтобы добавить туда следующую цифру, надо будет увеличить размер массива при помощи `realloc`. Или с самого начала выделите массив побольше, для учебного задания сойдёт.)

Затем, пробегитесь по массиву и "соберите" цифры в новое число по новому основанию:

```
currNumber = currNumber * 8 + nextDigit;
```

В C++ справиться с заданием было бы проще, поскольку там есть стандартные контейнеры, которые сами заботятся о низкоуровневых штуках типа выделения памяти.

Заметьте, однако, что код из Вашего вопроса переводит из 8-ричной в 10-ичную запись (а не из 2-ичной). Для двоичной, константу `8` надо заменить на `2`.

(Поскольку задание учебное, я не привожу полный код.)

---

Кстати, можно и не использовать промежуточный массив, а вычислять новое значение на лету:

```
int nextDigit = inputNumber % 10;
inputNumber = inputNumber / 10;
targetNumber = targetNumber * 8 + nextDigit;
```

(Идея содрана из ответа [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp))

Comment: Можно использовать только WHILE и ELSE IF использовать другие управляющие структуры, массивы и т.д. запрещено. Я не думаю, что это решение, даже если оно правильное подойдёт мне. Всё равно спасибо, что откликнулись.

Comment: @steelhouse: обновил ответ, теперь без циклов :) То есть, тьфу, без массивов!

Answer (score 1):

Ну если ты вводишь число как десятичное, то. Во-первых для чисел побольше лучше использовать тип long/unsigned long (на некоторых архитектурах это идентично int/unsigned int). Во-вторых есть операции / и %. и будет примерно

```
a10 = 0;
factor = 1;
while(number) {
   a10 += number%10 *factor;
   number /= 10;
   factor *= 2; // или factor <<= 1;
}
```

Примерно так: взять младшую цифру. Значение a10 увеличить на эту цифру, умноженную на степень двойки для этой цифры (накапливается в factor). Начинать с младшей цифры и до старшей. Число д.б. положительным.

Answer (score 0):

вот несколько вариантов:

1.запихивать все не в a1,a2,a3,a4 а в массив а[20]. тоесть вместо a1 - а[0], a2 - a[1]...
массив размером 20 (чтобы влезло максимальное число в 8байтов) все лишнее заполнять нулями или "-1"

2.использовать объединения  http://www.programmers.kz/2009/07/14/-obedineniya.html

Comment: Класс. Объединения -- это ведь union. За такие советы ТС имеет право набить советчику морду лица. Объяснять "за что" надо?

Comment: Можно использовать только WHILE и ELSE IF использовать другие управляющие структуры, массивы и т.д. запрещено. Я не думаю, что это решение, даже если оно правильное подойдёт мне. Всё равно спасибо, что откликнулись.