# Бинарная запись. С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary

```
Example:
For a set of six status inputs as shown for the ASCII data file in subclause 6.4.(0,0,0,0,1,1),
a) Write these status inputs as a binary number (110000), recognizing that the channels are listed low
bits first in the ASCII data file.
b) Then pad the number out to a 16 bit number (0000 0000 0011 0000).
c) Translate this to a hexadecimal value (00 30).
d) The data is then stored in LSB/MSB format (30 00).
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как производится запись? 
Есть файл с такими строками:

```
110000
110100
110001
```

Нужно правильно записать каждую строку.
Как это реализовать на c++.

Comment: Какой из пунктов вам не ясен?

Comment: Пункт d) вы уже спрашивали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809953/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%a1

Comment: Более того, я там даже вроде всё подробно ответил

Comment: Перевожу a) ввести число. b) дополнить нулями с)перевести в hex-форму d) перевести с "левостороннего" в "правосторонний" (сделать реверс байтов).

Comment: @vegorov уже вчитался, это дубль. Сессия - сложная будет.

Comment: Здесь не приветствуется выполнение заданий. Одна из причин - непонимание автора вопроса что в ответе. Ну.. незнаю... сходите на курсы, выучите системы счислений, выучите с++, или договоритесь как-то.

Comment: Спасибо за советы! прислушаюсь

Comment: Вот перевод с двоичной системы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/161094/17974

Comment: Вот хороший пример перевода с двоичной системы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749218/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-c

Comment: "Нужно правильно записать каждую строку" - записать в файл? Так и пишите в блокноте (notepad.exe).  В программу? Просто нажимаем 110000. Или вывести на экран - тогда это перевод в двоичную. Если число уже в двочной - выводим без изменений - но нужен кусок кода что б понимать где затык. Вопрос неполный.

Answer (score 0):

@nick_n_a 
Я записываю бинарный файл, и только первые 6 элементов вектора записываются правильно 30 00, остальные значения равны 00 00 
Записала вектор и файла.

```
input.txt

    0 0 0 0 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1     
    0 0 0 0 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1
    1 0 0 0 1 1




void writeVector(std::istream &Dfile)
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(Dfile), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(vectorValue));
    std::copy(vectorValue.begin(), vectorValue.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
};


for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
    {
        int index = i + 1;
        file.write((char *)&index, sizeof(int));

unsigned short m_bytesCount = 0;

for (size_t k = 1; k < 6; ++k)
        {

            if (vectorValue[++i2] == 1)
                m_bytesCount |= 1 << i2;
            else
                m_bytesCount = 0;
        }
        file.write((char *)&m_bytesCount, sizeof m_bytesCount);
}
```

Comment: это нужно писать в секцию вопрос, секция ответ - для ответов.

Comment: а зачем вы обнуляете `m_bytesCount = 0;` ? И что такое `i2` ?